# We giving a task for Lua table but it is not working as expectable

Tags: lua

Our task is create a table, and read values to the table using a loop. Print the values after the process is complete. - Create a table. - Read the number of values to be read to the table. - Read the values to the table using a loop. - Print the values in the table using another loop. for this we had written code as

```
local table = {}

for value in ipairs(table) do 
   io.read()
end

for value in ipairs(table) do
  print(value)
end
```

not sure where we went wrong please help us. Our exception is

```
Input (stdin)
3
11
22
abc

Your Output (stdout)
~ no output ~

Expected Output
11
22
abc
```

Correct Code is

```
local table1 = {} 
local x = io.read() 

for line in io.lines() do 
table.insert(table1, line) 
end 

for K, value in ipairs(table1) do
 print(value) 
end
```

Comment: Please refer to the manual for everything you use in your code. Your code clearly shows that you did not read what ipairs does. it does not make any sense to iterate over an empty table. Please read the Lua manual and ideally Programming the beasics chapters in Lua befor you continue

Comment: and like in your last question you still don't tell the user what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through this step-by-step.

1. Create a table.

Though the syntax is correct, `table` is a <strike>reserved</strike> pre-defined global name in Lua, and thus <strike>cannot</strike> should not be declared a variable name to avoid future issues. Instead, you'll need to want to use a different name. If you're insistent on using the word `table`, you'll have to distinguish it from the <strike>function</strike> global `table`. The easiest way to do this is change it to `Table`, as Lua is a case-sensitive language. Therefore, your table creation should look something like:

```
local Table = {}
```

2. Read values to the table using a loop.

Though `Table` is now established as a table, your `for` loop is only iterating through an empty table. It seems your goal is to iterate through the `io.read()` instead. But `io.read()` is probably not what you want here, though you can utilize a `repeat` loop if you wish to use `io.read()` via `table.insert`. However, `repeat` requires a condition that must be met for it to terminate, such as the length of the table reaching a certain amount (in your example, it would be `until (#Table == 4)`). Since this is a task you are given, I will not provide an example, but allow you to research this method and use it to your advantage.

3. Print the values after the process is complete.

You are on the right track with your printing loop. However, it must be noted that iterating through a table always returns two results, an `index` and a `value`. In your code, you would only return the `index` number, so your output would simply return:

```
1
2
3
4
```

If you are wanting the actual values, you'll need a placeholder for the index. Oftentimes, the placeholder for an unneeded variable in Lua is the underscore (`_`). Modify your `for` loop to account for the index, and you should be set.

Try modifying your code with the suggestions I've given and see if you can figure out how to achieve your end result.

Edited:

Thanks, Piglet, for corrections on the insight! I'd forgotten `table` itself wasn't a function, and wasn't reserved, but still bad form to use it as a variable name whether local or global. At least, it's how I was taught, but your comment is correct!

Comment: table is not a function. it is a global reference to Lua's table library. it is not a reserved name and it can be used. the only effect is that you'll need another reference to Lua's table library if you want to use it. other than that table is just a name like any other. in the given example the local table shadows the global table but it has no negative effect as no table-method is used.

Comment: thanks code worked as

`
local table1 = {}

local x = io.read()

for line in io.lines() do
table.insert(table1, line)
end

for K, value in ipairs(table1) do
  print(value)
end
`